# Angular 8 Multiple forms on one page

Tags: angular

I'm trying to build registration/login screen in angular 8 with some animation when switching between the 2 forms. I have 2 forms with validation, one for the registration and the other for login.  Both have their own form groups associated to them.  The issue I'm having is that when both are loaded into the parent, the registration form wont submit, nor will it validate.  If I comment out the login form, it works as intended.

Parent template:

```
            <div class="form-container">
              <div class="form login">
                <!--<app-login></app-login>-->
              </div>

              <div class="form register">
                <app-registration></app-registration>
              </div>


            </div>
```

Register template:

```
<form [formGroup]="registerFormModel" autocomplete="off" (submit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="form-group required">
    <input class="form-control" formControlName="Email" placeholder="Email">
    <label class="text-danger" *ngIf="registerFormModel.get('Email').touched && registerFormModel.get('Email').errors?.required">
      This
      field is mandatory.
    </label>
    <label class="text-danger" *ngIf="registerFormModel.get('Email').touched && registerFormModel.get('Email').errors?.email">
      Invalid
      email address.
    </label>
  </div>
  <div formGroupName="Passwords">
    <div class="form-group required">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" formControlName="Password" placeholder="Password">
      <label class="text-danger" *ngIf="registerFormModel.get('Passwords.Password').touched && registerFormModel.get('Passwords.Password').errors?.required">
        This
        field is mandatory.
      </label>
      <label class="text-danger" *ngIf="registerFormModel.get('Passwords.Password').touched && registerFormModel.get('Passwords.Password').errors?.minlength">
        Minimum
        4 characters required.
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group required">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" formControlName="ConfirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password">
      <label class="text-danger" *ngIf="registerFormModel.get('Passwords.ConfirmPassword').touched && registerFormModel.get('Passwords.ConfirmPassword').errors?.required">
        This
        field is mandatory.
      </label>
      <label class="text-danger" *ngIf="registerFormModel.get('Passwords.ConfirmPassword').touched && registerFormModel.get('Passwords.ConfirmPassword').errors?.passwordMismatch">
        Confirm
        Password does not match.
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" formControlName="first_name" placeholder="First Name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" formControlName="last_name" placeholder="Last Name">
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-8 offset-md-2">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-default" [disabled]="!registerFormModel.valid">Sign Up</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Register TS

```
export class RegistrationComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(
        private register: RegisterController,
        private fb: FormBuilder
/*, private toastr: ToastrService*/) { }


    registerFormModel = this.fb.group({
        first_name: [''],
        last_name: [''],
        Email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
        Passwords: this.fb.group({
            Password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)]],
            ConfirmPassword: ['', Validators.required]
        }, { validator: this.comparePasswords })

    });

    comparePasswords(fb: FormGroup) {
        let confirmPswrdCtrl = fb.get('ConfirmPassword');
        //passwordMismatch
        //confirmPswrdCtrl.errors={passwordMismatch:true}
        if (confirmPswrdCtrl.errors == null || 'passwordMismatch' in confirmPswrdCtrl.errors) {
            if (fb.get('Password').value != confirmPswrdCtrl.value)
                confirmPswrdCtrl.setErrors({ passwordMismatch: true });
            else
                confirmPswrdCtrl.setErrors(null);
        }
    }


  ngOnInit() {
      this.registerFormModel.reset();
  }

    onRegisterSubmit() {
        this.register.register(this.registerFormModel.value).subscribe(
            (res: any) => {
                if (res.succeeded) {
                    this.registerFormModel.reset();
                    window.location.href = '/';
                    //this.toastr.success('New user created!', 'Registration successful.');
                } else {
                    res.errors.forEach(element => {
                        switch (element.code) {
                            case 'DuplicateUserName':
                                //this.toastr.error('Username is already taken','Registration failed.');
                                break;

                            default:
                                //this.toastr.error(element.description,'Registration failed.');
                                break;
                        }
                    });
                }
            },
            err => {
                console.log(err);
            }
        );
    }

}
```

Login template:

```
<form [formGroup]="loginFormModel" class="mb-4" autocomplete="off" (submit)="onLoginSubmit()">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" formControlName="email" required placeholder="Email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" formControlName="Password" required placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex">
    <div class="">
      <a href="/reset-password">Forgot my password</a>
    </div>
    <div class="align-content-end flex-fill">
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="flex-fill text-right">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg " [disabled]="form.invalid">Login</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Login ts:

```
export class LoginComponent {

    loginFormModel = this.fb.group({
        email: [''],
        Password: ['']
    });


    constructor(
        private fb: FormBuilder,
        private login: LoginController,
        public globals: Globals
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    onLoginSubmit() {
        this.login.login(this.loginFormModel.value).subscribe(
            (res: any) => {
                this.globals.session = new ISession();

                this.globals.session = <ISession> res.object;
                this.globals.session.user = <IUser>res.object.user;

                localStorage.setItem('session', JSON.stringify(this.globals.session));

                window.location.href = '/';

            },
            err => {
                //this._snackBar.open('Error ' + err.status + ': ' + err.error);
                if (err.status == 400)
                    return;
                  //this.toastr.error('Incorrect username or password.', 'Authentication failed.');
                else
                    console.log(err);
            }
        );
    }




}
```

I'm sure its something stupid I've done, I just can't figure it out, thanks!

Comment: Does the login form submit and validate when both forms are on the page? You could try making both buttons type="button" and adding the (click) method to them, calling the appropriate submitting function for each one (the method you currently have in each form tag).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a hint, if you are a new developer, use dev tools in browser (pressing F12)! This would have helped you in this case, since the [console is throwing an error in your login component](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ejc7ad?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts) (when inspecting dev tools console):

> `TypeError: Cannot read property 'invalid' of undefined`

This is causing the issue that it seems that the registration form is not validating.

The error stems from `[disabled]="form.invalid"` in your login component. Your form is not named `form`, but  called `loginFormModel`, so fix it:

```
[disabled]="loginFormModel.invalid"
```

and the registrationform should work fine even when login form is visible:

**[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vyqqm5?file=src/app/login.component.ts)**

Comment: Oh my god, I knew it had to be something stupid.  I saw the invalid property, but I couldn't determine where it was coming from.  Guess that's what I get for staring at it for that long.  Thanks for the second pair of eyes!